# Como invocar un método llamado desde otro método utilizando el diccionario en Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, método, diccionarios

La idea es llamar al método de la clase pasando parámetro `str`,
utilizar el diccionario para evitar cadenas de `if` a la hora de buscar la función. Al llamar al método `ejecutar` guarda en `df` el método que se quiere invocar, pero con la sintaxis `self.df()` en reemplazo de `self.fun1()` esta buscando `fb` como un método de `Cl` en vez de invocar como variable local.
Si llamo directamente `df()` seria como ejecutar `Cl.fun1()`, y no utiliza la instancia, por consecuente no tiene el parámetro `"fun1"`

```
class Cl():

    def __init__(self, funcion):
        self.funcion = funcion

    def ejecutar(self):
        df = self.dic[self.funcion]
        print(df)
        self.df() # aqui el punto

    def fun1(self):
        print("en fun 1")

    def fun2(self):
        print("en fun 2")

    dic = {"fun1": fun1, "fun2": fun2}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cl = Cl("fun1")
    cl.ejecutar()
```

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto, al utilizar el diccionario se pierde la linea del `self`
entonces tendría que pasarse como parametro

```
df(self)
```

respuesta de *Cristian Hernan Schmidt*